# Elixir - Can't get to Record.extract between 2 Deps

Tags: rabbitmq, record, elixir

I'm new to Elixir, and Erlang, so I might have skiped something basic but ...

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ within Elixir, and use a Elixir based lib (d0rc/exrabbit)

When mix deps.get , it get stuck, twice. The first problem is that dorc's exrabbit works on elixir 0.10.2-dev, and I'm running on 0.11.2 ... Soooo I just want to try to force it, just in case it works. Maybe that's the problem here :p

The second problem comes once I force deps to accept elixir to be higher.

```
mix deps.get
* Compiling exrabbit
Compiled lib/exrabbit/behaviour.ex
Compiled lib/exrabbit/supervisor.ex
== Compilation error on file lib/exrabbit.ex ==
could not compile dependency exrabbit, mix compile failed. You can recompile this dependency with `mix deps.compile exrabbit` or update it with `mix deps.update exrabbit`
** (RuntimeError) error parsing file /Users/-----/dev/testmongo/_build/shared/lib/rabbit_common/include/rabbit_framing.hrl, got: {:error, :enoent}
    /private/tmp/elixir-PzZu/elixir-0.11.2/lib/elixir/lib/record/extractor.ex:54: Record.Extractor.read_file/1
    /private/tmp/elixir-PzZu/elixir-0.11.2/lib/elixir/lib/record/extractor.ex:32: Record.Extractor.retrieve_record/2
    deps/exrabbit/lib/exrabbit.ex:10: (module)
    deps/exrabbit/lib/exrabbit.ex:9: (file)
```

The code in question is the following :

```
defmodule Exrabbit.Framing do
 defrecord :'P_basic', Record.extract(:'P_basic', from_lib: "rabbit_common/include/rabbit_framing.hrl")
end
```

It seems from my point of view, that it isn't fetching information at the right place.

I checked and "rabbit_common/include/rabbit_framing.hrl" does indeed exists but not within _build directory, but within deps. Which makes sense to me.

I guess I'll have to look up in elixir patch notes if there have been updates on Record.extract that would imply something like this ... Is there something I've been missing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in Elixir where include was not working when we moved to the new build style. Please try Elixir master, where this bug is fixed (sorry for the troubles!).

Comment: Hi, I've tried with Elixir master but had no success with it either ... Current head commit is f4144a63f835b91cf4c3d9f38166480bb2ea59d3 . (not sure i did the right thing, I've simply cloned from repo, make, and directly used elixir/bin/mix to compile my project )

Comment: Thanks a million, after a fresh reinstall of all depency it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you're getting that error, as that seems to be mostly correct.  I ran into very similar problems just now with the `cthulhuology/Amqp` package, and here's how I fixed it: https://github.com/cthulhuology/Amqp/pull/1

However, exrabbit seems to be mostly doing it properly.  Not sure, but hopefully that PR can be of assistance since it just resolved an identical error for me.

Comment: From what I see from your diff, you simply upgraded your elixir version, like José Valim said, but it didn't work out for me ... i'll try a fresh install :)

Comment: I just saw this.... I also modified the Record.extract call to use `from_lib` rather than `from`